# MATLAB LOOPS: Inserting values from a big array to a small array

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a vector named signal consisting of 300001 values. In each iteration of the for loop, I want to pick up 2000 consecutive values from this vector and store it in another vector X (X is 1*2000 vector)
The code is as follows:

```
D = 1:300001;
A = zeros(1,2000);
r=1;
n=0;
m=1;

for i=1:300001
   for p = (1+(2000*n)):(r*2000) 
        while m<2000
        A(1,m)= signal(1,p);
        %disp (m);
        m = m+1; 
        end

   end
r = r+1;
n = n+1; 
m = 1;

end
```

But it gives me the error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Can somebody help me out with a better way to do it?

Comment: First iteration should have values from 1 to 2000 taken from signal and put into X, second from 2001 to 4000 from signal to X and so on..

Answer (score 0):

this would work

```
signal = ones(1,30000);
index1= 1:2000:length(signal);
index2= 2000:2000:length(signal);


for i=1:length(index1)
   A = signal(index1(i):index2(i));
end
```

or this

```
signal = ones(1,30000);
temp = reshape(signal,2000,[]);
for i = 1:size(temp,2)
    A=temp(:,i);
end
```